# I deleted appcompat_v7 from folder

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

I didn't know what appcompat_v7 was meant for til now. Unknowingly, I deleted it not just from the Package Explorer but also its physical file folder, now, my apps won't work because of this. I tried looking for it by Importing from the Library and even installed the Android Support Library from SDK Manager, and I still can't find it. How do I fix this?

Comment: Use Android Studio, the IDE that has replaced the deprecated ADT since like more than a year ago?

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are using android studio, follow these steps
1. Remove it from build.gradle dependency list(  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+') and restart android studio.
2. Now add the appcompat library back again, and click on sync at top right of build.gradle. It will download and install again.
```